# Nodejs User login System

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Am looking for some information on how to create a node.js login system, I have came across a lot of examples using express.

But am looking for some direction on how to do this without using express.

The main reason behind this is that my login webpages will be hosted on an apache server and my node.js server application will be running on a different server running mongoDB.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Thanks,
Iain

Comment: There is a great article about on how to store passwords using mongoose, which I recommend when using node.js+mongodb. The article also covers how to authenticate users: http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/stop-storing-passwords-already/

Comment: I don't know if I explained my self well,  I have a html page hosted on an apache server and I need to post form data from that to a node.js application on a different server.

Comment: So the contents served by your Apache shall be protected by login? The above suggestions are for Node.js to authenticate a login session, the client could send the session cookie (from Node's login success response) to the Apache server and the Apache server communicate to Node to verify the login.

Comment: Are you facing [CORS problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and how to store passwords in mongodb from node? I use nginx to solve CORS and as @MaksimsMihejevs pointed it correctly, I suggest using passport and passport-local. You can implement your own authentication as passport is extremely modular. Also look at mongoose to interact with mongodb from node.

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you didn't want solutions using express. But you may want to checkout Drywall for other inspiration. There are a lot of problems we solved and I'm sure there are some take-a-ways you could use.

<del>Drywall</del> Aqua - A website and user system for Node.js:
https://jedireza.github.io/aqua/

Comment: i came across for the same thing he was asking for, i wanted to make the user system and session handling without any framework, but after seeing this inspiring page, now i think its worth a try for express

Answer (score 0):

## SweetAuth

#### A lightweight, zero-configuration user authentication module which doesn't depend on a database.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweet-auth

It's simple as:

```
app.get('/private-page', (req, res) => {

    if (req.user.isAuthorized) {
        // user is logged in! send the requested page
        // you can access req.user.email
    }
    else {
        // user not logged in. redirect to login page
    }
})
```

With this, you have the flexibility to point your front end pages in a separate server to a nodejs in another server.